# graphicImage not correct url

Tags: jsf, url, primefaces, graphicimage

I've the following primefaces component, it should just load images that are under `/WEB-INF/Resource/{1.png,2.png,3.png,4.png}`.

```
<p:ring id="weatherForecasts" value="#{eventPageCreatorBean.weatherForecasts}" var="weatherForecast" styleClass="image-ring" easing="easeInOutBack">
    <p:panelGrid columns="1">
        #{weatherForecast.forecastStart}
        <p:graphicImage id="img" name="/WEB-INF/Resources/images/#{weatherForecast.weatherCondition.code}.png" />
        #{weatherForecast.forecastEnd}
    </p:panelGrid>
</p:ring>
```

By checking on the source code from the browser I get this path:

```
/meteocal-web/javax.faces.resource//WEB-INF/Resources/images/1.png.xhtml
```

Anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11988415/1391249). (Store them into a folder named `resources` under the root of your application).

Answer (score 1):

In JSF2, all your web-resources files like CSS, images or .js files, can be put in a `resources` folder, under the root of your web application (same level as `WEB-INF`).

```
>webapp
   |
   -->resources
   |      |
   |      -->images
   |           |
   |           1.png
   -->WEB-INF
```

Then you will be able to refer to the corresponding folder as `library`:

```
<p:graphicImage id="img" 
                library="images" 
                name="#{weatherForecast.weatherCondition.code}.png}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I try with this solution but it doesn't work now there is an error as:

[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (RES_NOT_FOUND, line 0)

I've tried either with or without the second } .

Comment: It should be working. Are you sure your `code` is a valid value for an existing picture

Comment: I wouldn't advocate the word "images" as library name. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used